# RecyclerView in Fragment not accepting OnClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `fragment` class in my `MainActivity` which contains a `recyclerview`. I want to call `onClickItem` type of function so that I can play the tapped song name on the list. But my `onClick` is not working.

[image]

This is the `adapter` for my `recyclerview`

```
public class NowPlayingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NowPlayingAdapter.PlayViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Audio> list = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
private static final String TAG = "operation";

public interface NowPlayingInterface {
    void onSongClick(int position);
}

public NowPlayingInterface nowPlayingInterface;

public NowPlayingAdapter(ArrayList<Audio> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    if(context instanceof NowPlayingAdapter.NowPlayingInterface){
        nowPlayingInterface = (NowPlayingInterface) context;
    }
}

@Override
public NowPlayingAdapter.PlayViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_list_item,parent,false);
    PlayViewHolder holder = new PlayViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NowPlayingAdapter.PlayViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final int pos = position;
    holder.songName.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.duration.setText(list.get(position).getDuration());
    holder.album.setText(list.get(position).getAlbum());
    holder.removeItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Audio item = HomeFragment.audioList.get(pos);
            HomeFragment.audioList.remove(item);
            Log.e(TAG, "Remove: " );
            HomeFragment.nowPlayingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.e(TAG, "Change: " );


        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class PlayViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView songName, album, duration;
    ImageButton removeItem;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    public PlayViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_list_item);
        songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.songname);
        album = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.album);
        duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        removeItem = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_item_button);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==layout && nowPlayingInterface!=null)
        nowPlayingInterface.onSongClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
}
```

And this is my `fragment` class where I want to call the click function on my `recyclerview`.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements NowPlayingAdapter.NowPlayingInterface {

protected RecyclerView currentPlaylistRecyclerView;
public static ArrayList<Audio> audioList = new ArrayList<>();
public static NowPlayingAdapter nowPlayingAdapter;
protected LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

private TextView selectedSong = null;
private SeekBar seekBar = null;
private MediaPlayer player = null;
private ImageButton playButton = null;
private ImageButton prevButton = null;
private ImageButton nextButton = null;
private boolean isStarted = false;
private boolean isMovingSeekBar = false;
private String currentFile = null;
private String songName = null;
private String albumName = null;
private String duration = null;
private int filePosition;

private static final String TAG = "LibraryFragment";
private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
private static final int SEEK = 5000;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updatePosition();
    }
};

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //fetchLocalAudioFiles();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    rootView.setTag(TAG);

    currentPlaylistRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.now_playing);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext());
    nowPlayingAdapter = new NowPlayingAdapter(audioList,container.getContext());
    currentPlaylistRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    currentPlaylistRecyclerView.setAdapter(nowPlayingAdapter);

    playButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.play);
    prevButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prev);
    nextButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    selectedSong = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.selected_file);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);

    playButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
    prevButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSongClick(int position) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Change: " );
    Audio item = audioList.get(position);
    filePosition = position;
    currentFile = item.getData();
    songName = item.getTitle();
    albumName = item.getAlbum();
    duration = item.getDuration();
    startPlay(currentFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click listener in your adapter use something like **nowPlayingInterface.onSongClick(position)** In this way your fragment will be able to handle the click event and will start playing the song (hopefully).

Comment: getAdapterPosition() does a completely different thing. Here you can have a look at the documentation for this method - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition()

Comment: Then, how should I take the position of the tapped item?

Comment: In **onBindViewHolder()** the 3rd parameter is the position of the item.

Comment: I cannot store the position from **onBindViewHolder** and I don't know how to use `nowPlayingInterface.onSongClick(position)` within it.

Comment: When I simply place this function in **onBindViewHolder()** then it throws a Null Pointer Exception

Comment: It's normal to throw you a null pointer exception, because the instance of NowPlayingInterface is NULL. Let's continue this discussion in a chat room and I will explain you how to solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157842/discussion-between-veloxigami-and-todor-kostov).

Comment: I'm having the same problem again. I really forgot how to initialize my Interface so that it's not null. I lost my project due to hdd corruption. Rebuilding the whole project again from the start.

Comment: Make a setInterface() method in your adapter. And in your Activity implement your interface. Then use adapter.setInterface(this) in your Activity.

Comment: Thank you for your help @todor

Answer (score 2):

You could consider adding the setOnClickListener method inside your ViewHolder

```
public class PlayViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
TextView songName, album, duration;
ImageButton removeItem;
RelativeLayout layout;

public PlayViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_list_item);
    songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.songname);
    album = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.album);
    duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    removeItem = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_item_button);
    //Setup for which view the onclick should be called
    layout.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //since only 1 view has been setup for listening, no need of checking it's id
    if(nowPlayingInterface!=null)
    nowPlayingInterface.onSongClick(getAdapterPosition());
}
```

inside the onClick of this viewholder your can call 
`nowPlayingInterface.onSingleClick();`

More on interfaces here https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners

Extra - 
I don't know where exactly you require a RelativeLayout object, but if it used only for detecting click in your item, then you may get rid of it and simply use `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`

Another suggestion, if `itemView` (or `layout`) is the only view that you are setting up for onClick in the Viewholder, you may avoid a check for it's id.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the position in your onBindViewHolder(), setTag the position for itemView

```
holder.itemView.setTag(position);
```

Then you can get the position in your onClick using

```
int index = (int) view.getTag();
```

Hope this helps

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the help but it's still in the same state. I found a way to make the clicking on the item work using `gestureDetector` and dimensions of the `itemView` ([Used this for it](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/)) but now my button's `onClick()` which is present in every item is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to set onClickListener to listen for click events.

```
 public PlayViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_list_item);
    songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.songname);
    album = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.album);
    duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    removeItem = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_item_button);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```